# VBA - Using RefEdit as Range

Tags: vba, excel, user-controls, userform

I have a VBA script which opens a UserForm so the user can select various cell addresses for copying information from one file to another.  I am using RefEdit controls to designate the cell address, but I am receiving an object error when I try to use the `Workbook.Range(UserForm.RefEdit.Value)` function, because the RefEdit reference is in the format "'Sheet1'!X#:X#".  I know that if the RefEdit were just a range of cells I could do `Workbook.Worksheet.Range(UserForm.RefEdit.Value)`, but the VBA script is being used for transitioning multiple files with different sheet names (so I can't use a universal `Workbook.Worksheet` string).  Is there any way to use the RefEdit reference with both sheet name and cell address as a range?

Here is my current code:

```
Sub ReviseFAA()
Dim FolderPath As String, FilePath As String
Dim SourceFAA As Workbook, RevisedFAA As Workbook

FolderPath = "A:\Copy of MWO File\"
FilePath = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls")

Do While FilePath <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & "FAA Template.xlsx")
    Set RevisedFAA = Workbooks("FAA Template.xlsx")
    Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & FilePath)
    Set SourceFAA = Workbooks(FilePath)

    FAA_User.Show

    With SourceFAA
    RevisedFAA.Sheets("Repair Instruction").Range("U2:AD3") = .Range(FAA_User.ControlNumber.Value).Value
    End With

    FilePath = Dir
Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Range(UserForm.RefEdit.Value)
```

Remove the `workbook`. and `worksheet`.

Comment: I checked my settings, and the R1C1 reference style was unchecked, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I need to at least have the Workbook expression to identify the source Workbook, as I have two different files open at the same time (the template and and source Workbook).  If I remove the `Worksheet` and just have `Workbook.Range(Userform.RefEdit.Value)`, I still receive an object error.  I have tried `With Workbook` and `.Range(UserForm.RefEdit.Value)`, but still the same error.

Comment: no, remove everything just leave the code above. The expression UserForm.RefEdit.Value will take into account the fact that you are using a different file

Comment: @VBA Programmer Thank you!  I did not realize that the UserForm would take into account the Workbook as well, since the string only indicates a Sheet and Cell reference!  You just saved me from having to write unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: Np, glad I could help. And apparently, CRondao mentioned this we just didn't see it :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it worked:

```
Dim s, w
s = RefEdit1.Value
Set w = Range(s)
MsgBox w.Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: I believe that often works, but I am trying to retrieve a value from a range of merged cells, which is why I think I'm having the Range Object issue.  I might just have to split the string to separate the Sheet and Cell Range.

Comment: Well, that is a very important information, and you did not refer that... :)

Comment: I apologize, I am afraid I will bore everyone if I include too many details, but I will post my current code in the event there is something else I might be doing wrong!